# I am having trouble with web2py routes.example.py

Tags: error-handling, web2py

Hi I would like to ask a question about routes.example.py
My app is called "HelloWorld"

If I use following URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/helloWorld/default/index
```

The user is guided to the main page.

I am trying to figure out handling errors.

For example If I have a following URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/helloWorld/default/index11
```

I have to handle the error.

Based on my research, I know that I need to work on "routes.example.py"

The following is my work in routes.example.py

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
from fileutils import abspath
from languages import read_possible_languages

possible_languages = read_possible_languages(abspath('applications', app))

routers = {
app: dict(
    default_language = possible_languages['default'][0],
    languages = [lang for lang in possible_languages
                       if lang != 'default']
)
}
*** above part is given by the web2py***
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

default_application = "HelloWorld"
default_controller = "default"
default_function = "index"

routes_onerror = [
('HelloWorld/400', '/HelloWorld/default/login'),
('HelloWorld/*', '/HelloWorld/static/fail.html'),
('*/404', '/HelloWorld/static/cantfind.html'),
('*/*', '/HelloWorld/error/index')
]
```

I define the default application, default controller and default fuction
Bases on these, I define the error cases in routes_onerror...

Can you tell me that what I am missing?

Comment: Is the application name "helloWorld" or "HelloWorld"? Also, `default_application`, etc. are for use with the pattern-based rewrite system -- don't use them if you are using the parameter-based system (i.e., when using `routers`).

Comment: It is "HelloWorld." Even if I remove default_application, default_controller, default function, I am having problems.  When I type "http://127.0.0.1:8000/HelloWorld/default/index111" I get "invalid function (default/index111)". I would like to direct the user to specific pages that I have created (such as canfind.html)..

Comment: Have you renamed the file to `routes.py`, put it in the root /web2py directory, and re-started the server?

Comment: Yes I did... still, it is not working.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is working. There was silly typos..  Do you mind if i ask you another quick question? Where can I find or create "/HelloWorld/error/index" and '/HelloWorld/default/login'?? Are they controllers? is that the reason why they do not end with .html?

Comment: "error" would refer to an error.py controller, and "index" would refer to an `index` function in that controller. When no extension is specified, "html" is assumed, so you would have an associated /views/error/index.html view. Similarly for /default/login.